# DI container for Java without @Inject

Tags: java, dependency-injection

I'd like to know if there is any DI container for Java world that behaves close to .NET ones, namely, I want these 2 features:

- main requirement - it should work without @Inject annotation. So, if @Inject is not specified anywhere, and class has single constructor then container should use this constructor. I know, @Inject annotation is standard, but I don't like it.
- 2nd requirement (not necessary at all) - any way to auto-configure (by some naming conventions etc.)

It looks like Swing and Guice require @Inject, but I will be happy, if I'm wrong.

Comment: _constructor then container should use this constructor._ That's a really bad convention imo.

Comment: [WHY EJB 3.1 AND CDI ARE GOOD JAVA EE 6 FRIENDS](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/why_ejb_3_1_and)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis why so? Constructor injection is safest and best way to inject dependencies. It's the best to have single constructor. So, in my practice, 99% classes will have `@Inject` annotation for single constructor, and I want to avoid these repetitions.

Comment: That's just asking for trouble. What happens if someone else later adds a new constructor and there's ambiguity about which should be called? Whether constructor injection is "best" is highly debatable (what about dependencies that get a `this` reference before the object is live?).

Comment: @chrylis "If someone else later adds a new constructor", he will mark one of constructors with `@Inject`. Regarding 2nd question - honestly, I don't get it. But anyway - in any special case I can use standard CDI annotations. But from my experience - 99% of cases will be constructor injection with single constructor. I used this convention for 2 years in huge .NET application, and it never leads me to troubles. Instead, property/method injections have (IMHO) much more cons.

Comment: Most containers these days are using direct field setting rather than method injections, which, in combination with `@PostConstruct`, I've found to be more predictable and flexible.

Comment: @chrylis What about tests? It's easier to manage them (and mocks) when you use constructor injection. What if you will decide to use your component without DI container? If you use constructor injection, and you add another dependency - your code doesn't compile. At all. In case of field injection - it will compile, started, and failed in run-time because some of dependency will be null. I prefer failure during compile time. Anyway - this is NOT a question "what should I use - constructor/field injection". It's a question about specific feature of DI containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pico](http://picocontainer.com/) satisfies 1st requirement. 2nd requirement can be more or less done with [org.reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9571146/776448)